# Typeahead and clickable suggestion link

Tags: javascript, php, typeahead.js

i have this code in search.php:

```
<?php

    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
    $db=mysql_select_db("db",$con);
    $query=mysql_query("select * from users where username LIKE '%{$key}%'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
      $array[] =$row['code'].$row['id'];

    }
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

And this script in Javascript

```
<script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY', 
        href : 'profile.php?id='

        });
});
    </script>
<script>
    $('input.typeahead').on( 'typeahead:selected', function(event, datum) {

  window.location = "profile.php?id=" 
});
    </script>
```

I'm not very handy with js and API of typeahead, then i ask you:
There is another function to make a suggestion the url link?

The syntax is

> profile.php?id=$id

I am using the window.location but I can not pass the user id in the variable array
Thanks

Comment: ouch, that's quite an unsafe query you have there, please read up [on injection](http://bobby-tables.com), and learn PDO or mysqli (`i` is for improved). The `mysql` extension of old is deprecated

Comment: I am not sure what you are getting as $id here but you have to use profile.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?> instead.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old but, I'll leave a solution that worked for me for the same exact issue.

You need to use a [custom template](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#custom-templates) to achive this.

```
$('input.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: restaurants.ttAdapter(),
    templates:{
      suggestion:function(data) {
        return "<a href=""profile.php?id="  + data.id + ">"+ data.name +"</a>"
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to stop next propagation of event:

```
    $('#myFormID').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
      ev.stopPropagation();
    });
```